# Adding extra dropdown list in specific td on button click

Tags: javascript, html-table

We have a specific functionality where we need to add dynamic rows. In each of the row for the third column there is a button to add combo where it should be able to add extra combo in that  cell. We have tried appendChild but is not working. Any idea how to add extra combo boxes. Below is the codes and function to do that is addSubRow.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
        function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
                newcell.innerHTML = newcell.innerHTML +"<br> TEST";
                //alert(newcell.childNodes);
                /*switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                    case "text":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                            newcell.childNodes[0].id = "input" + rowCount;
                            break;
                    case "checkbox":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                            newcell.childNodes[0].id = "checkbox" + rowCount;     
                            break;
                    case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        newcell.childNodes[0].id = "select" + rowCount; 
                            break;
                }*
                if(newcell.childNodes[0].type=="button")
                {
                    alert("TEST");
                    newcell.childNodes[0].id=rowCount;
                }*/
            }

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
                  row.id="row"+i;
                  row.name="row"+i;
                  var rowName = "row"+i;
               //iterate through rows
               //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
               for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                 //iterate through columns
                 //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
                 col.id="col_"+i+"_"+j;
                   col.name="col_"+i+"_"+j;
                 var cels = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[j];
                 var realKids = 0,count = 0;
                 kids = cels.childNodes.length;
                 while(count < kids){
                        if(cels.childNodes[i].nodeType != 3){
                            realKids++;
                        }
                        count++;
                    }
                    alert("I : "+i+"   "+"J : "+j+"  "+"realKids :"+cels.childElementCount);
                //alert();

               }  
            }
        }

        function addSubRow(tableID,colID) {

            var tdID = document.getElementById(colID);



            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var comboBox1 = table.rows[0].cells[2].childNodes[1];
            comboBox1 = comboBox1;

      tdID.appendChild(comboBox1);
      //tdID.appendChild(comboBox1);
      //tdID.appendChild(comboBox1);
        }

        function deleteRow(tableID) {
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                    if(rowCount <= 1) {
                        alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                        break;
                    }
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }


            }
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
                  row.id="row"+i;
               //iterate through rows
               //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
               for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                 //iterate through columns
                 //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
                 //alert("J : "+j);
                 col.id="col"+i;
                 if(j==0)
                 {

                 }
                 else if(j==1)
                 {

                }
               }  
            }

            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }

    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

    <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

    <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
        <TR>
            <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
            <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txt"/></TD>
            <TD id="col_0_2">
                <INPUT type="button" value="Add Combo" onclick="addSubRow('dataTable','col_0_2')" />
                <SELECT name="country">
                    <OPTION value="in">India</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="de">Germany</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="fr">France</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="us">United States</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="ch">Switzerland</OPTION>
                </SELECT>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you really want, but here's a working function `addSubRow` function for appending a combobox.

I added some comments to explain what I did:

```
function addSubRow(tableID,colID) {
    var tdID = document.getElementById(colID);
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    // Create a new combobox element
    var new_comboBox = document.createElement('select');

    // Define / Add new combobox's attributes here
    //new_comboBox.setAttribute('id', 'something');
    // ...
    // ...

    // Add new combobox's options - you may use a 'for' loop...
    var option_1 = document.createElement('option');
    option_1.setAttribute('value', '1');
    var txt_1 = document.createTextNode("OPTION 1");
    option_1.appendChild(txt_1);

    var option_2 = document.createElement('option');
    option_2.setAttribute('value', '2');
    var txt_2 = document.createTextNode("OPTION 2");
    option_2.appendChild(txt_2);

    var option_3 = document.createElement('option');
    option_3.setAttribute('value', '3');
    var txt_3 = document.createTextNode("OPTION 3");
    option_3.appendChild(txt_3);
    // ... 
    // ...

    // Appending options to the new combobox
    new_comboBox.appendChild(option_1);
    new_comboBox.appendChild(option_2);
    new_comboBox.appendChild(option_3);
    // ... 
    // ...

    // Appending the combobox to the TD
    tdID.appendChild(new_comboBox);
}
```

**PS:**

- Pay attention when defining the combobox's attributes and its options' attributes
- I don't think that you need to use the table's ID `tableID`, in your function. You may simplify your function `addSubRow` by rmoving this argument?

Hope this helps mate.

Comment: What I need is first to be able to add the rows dynamically which I am able to do it ready. My next part is in the cells itself I should be able to add more drop down list can I just copy over the first original list as the list should be same one. I need you help in how to do it dynamically to add and remove the dropdown list in the cells? Am I clearer now?

Comment: I am trying this but is not happening var new_comboBox = table.rows[0].cells[2].childNodes[1].innerHTML;  tdID.appendChild(new_comboBox);

Comment: I have running through a loop to find all the elements types in column and to my surprise it shows the [0] undefined and [1] button and [2] also undefined ? Any reason why is [0] is not the button ?